# Jenkins difference between downstream and subproject

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins. I have seen a few jobs having other jobs as downstream job. Similarly, few other jobs having other jobs as sub-project.

Both seems to be doing the same thing (ie. running other jobs). What is the difference between the two approaches and when to use which?

Answer (score 0):

I facing some of the consequences of there being a difference in the first place right now.

The answer below is based on some materials I've read so I do not claim it to be a complete explanation. Hope it helps though!

By default, when a build is triggered using the "**Build other projects**" post-build step, then it's automatically treated as a downstream project.

According to [the official Jenkins glossary](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/)'s definition for a downstream project is:

> **Downstream** A configured Pipeline or Project which is triggered as part of the execution of a separate Pipeline or Project.

Unfortunately, this very vague description doesn't quite fit in the existence of the [the Parametrized Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) as a valid build step.

Due to two reasons, I am using [the Parametrized Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to call other jobs from mine (it's a plain freestyle project).

1. reason #1 - the triggered/called/downstream job has input parameters - I cannot pass them using the "**Build other projects**" post-build step
2. reason #2 - I need artifacts from the triggered/called/downstream job for 2 more steps of my job so using post-build steps is not an option for me.

I'm quoting the tooltip of the "**Downstream build of**" option of the "**Copy artifacts from another project**" build step (from [the Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)):

> Copy artifacts from a build that is a downstream of a build of the
>   specified project. You can use variable expressions.
>
> Downstream builds are found using fingerprints of files. That is, a
>   build that is triggerd from a build isn't always considered
>   downstream, but you need to fingerprint files used in builds to let
>   Jenkins track them.
>
> Note: "Downsteram build of" is applicable only to AbstractProject
>   based projects (both upstream and downstream projects).
>
> AbstractProject based projects: Freestyle projects Multi-configuration
>   projects Maven projects Non AbstractProject based projects: Pipeline
>   jobs (aka. Workflow jobs)

Lots of fun! Although this explanation is quite technical, I don't see how it helps me or you. 
What I ended up doing was to use the "**Specific build**" option of that step instead.
As the **Build Number** parameter required to use this option I used a variable injected by [the Parametrized Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin):

> TRIGGERED_BUILD_NUMBER_="Last build number triggered"

**In conclusion**: Jenkins has an understanding of what downstream projects are, but some plugins like the Parametrized Trigger plugin do things in their own way so they are treated in a different way and we have to keep this in mind when chaining jobs together.